# Linux assigns an fe80::/64 address to an interface. Shouldn't that be fe80::/10?

Tags: linux, networking, network-interface, ipv6

Per the IPv6 standard, Linux assigns IPv6 link local addresses to interfaces. These interfaces are always assigned /64 addresses. Is this correct? I would think they should be /10. Why are they assigned /64 addresses?

Comment: This related question may be of interest as well: https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/q/130/5842

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The address space allocated to link-local addresses is fe80::/10, but the next 54 bits are defined to be all zeroes, so the effective range is fe80::/64. Which puts it in line with the usual custom for IPv6 addresses.

[RFC 4291](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4291#section-2.5.6):

> ```
> 2.5.6.  Link-Local IPv6 Unicast Addresses
>
>    Link-Local addresses are for use on a single link.  Link-Local
>    addresses have the following format:
>
>    |   10     |
>    |  bits    |         54 bits         |          64 bits           |
>    +----------+-------------------------+----------------------------+
>    |1111111010|           0             |       interface ID         |
>    +----------+-------------------------+----------------------------+
> ```

Answer (score 0):

FE80::/64 includes 2^48 Ethernet addresses and some other link-level derived combinations, but not necessarily all types.  The /10 allows for future expansion of new types not yet defined.